# Sequences in coin flipping using Hoeffding's Inequality

Tags: probability

let $n\geqslant3$. We flip a coin $n$ times independently with probability $p$ to fall on $”1“$.

Let $X_{n}$ the number of sequences $\left(1,1,1\right)$ in the rows.

Show that for all $a>0$ using hoeffding's inequality:

$\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{X_{n}}{n-2}-p^{3}\right|\geqslant a\right)\leqslant6\exp\left(-\frac{a^{2}}{2\lceil\frac{n}{3}\rceil}\right)$

---

Let $p_{1},\ldots,p_{n}$ indicator random variables that gets $1$ if the i'th result is  "$1$", and $Y_{1},\ldots,Y_{n-2}$ indicator random variables that gets $1$ if the trio that starts at the i'th place contains only "$1$", I defined:

$Z_{i}=\frac{Y_{i}}{\left(n-2\right)}-\frac{p^{3}}{\left(n-2\right)}$ s.t. ${\sum}Z_{i}=\frac{X_{n}}{n-2}-p^{3}$

and I divided $Z_i$ to three disjoint (each of size $\lceil\frac{n-2}{3}\rceil $ at most) sets according to $i\mod3$ such that each set contains independent random variables and $\left|Z_{i}\right|\leqslant1$ and $\mathbb{E}\left[Z_{i}\right]=0$, so therefore we can apply hoeffding's inequality for each set separately, but I couldn't get the exact bound:

$\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{X_{n}}{n-2}-p^{3}\right|\geqslant a\right)=\,\,\,\,\,\mathbb{P}\left(\left|{\sum}Z_{i}\right|\geqslant a\right)\,\,\,\,\,=\,\,\,\,\,\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\underset{i\mod3=1}{\sum}\,\,Z_{i}\right|+\left|\underset{i\mod3=2}{\sum}\,\,Z_{i}\right|+\left|\underset{i\mod3=3}{\sum}\,\,Z_{i}\right|\geqslant a\right)$
$\leqslant\,\,\,\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{ \left|\underset{i\mod3=1}{\sum}\,\,Z_{i}\right|\geqslant\frac{a}{3}\right\} \,\,\,\bigcup\,\,\,\left\{ \left|\underset{i\mod3=2}{\sum}\,\,Z_{i}\right|\geqslant\frac{a}{3}\right\} \,\,\,\bigcup\,\,\,\left\{ \left|\underset{i\mod3=3}{\sum}\,\,Z_{i}\right|\geqslant\frac{a}{3}\right\} \right)$

$\leqslant\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\underset{i\mod3=1}{\sum}\,\,Z_{i}\right|\geqslant\frac{a}{3}\right)\,\,+\,\,\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\underset{i\mod3=2}{\sum}\,\,Z_{i}\right|\geqslant\frac{a}{3}\right)\,\,+\,\,\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\underset{i\mod3=3}{\sum}\,\,Z_{i}\right|\geqslant\frac{a}{3}\right)$

$\leqslant2\exp\left(-\frac{\left(\frac{a}{3}\right)^{2}}{2\lceil\frac{n-2}{3}\rceil}\right)\,\,+\,\,2\exp\left(-\frac{\left(\frac{a}{3}\right)^{2}}{2\lceil\frac{n-2}{3}\rceil}\right)\,\,+\,\,2\exp\left(-\frac{\left(\frac{a}{3}\right)^{2}}{2\lceil\frac{n-2}{3}\rceil}\right)$

$\leqslant\,6\exp\left(-\frac{a^{2}}{18\lceil\frac{n-2}{3}\rceil}\right)$